# Javascript: function as hash value

Tags: javascript

I want to call different functions depending on the input I find. If the input matches one of the keys, I want to call the corresponding function - with some parameters:

```
var commands = {
  'key1': someFunction,
  'key2': otherFunction
};
```

The keys are strings and to make it easier I created the command_keys variable:

```
var command_keys = Object.keys(commands);
```

I define the two functions further down:

```
function someFunction(param) {
 // do sth.
};

function otherFunction(param) {
 // do sth. else
};
```

Then I have a condition checking for the key and calling one of the functions depending on what key I found:

```
if (command_keys.indexOf(some_string) > -1) {
  index = command_keys.indexOf(some_string);
  commands[index](some_param);
}
```

However, I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: commands[index] is not a function(anonymous function)
```

Thank you for your ideas.

Comment: What's `some_array`? It would be better if you show us the full script.

Comment: So if `command_keys` is an array, then `index` is an integer and `commands` does not have integer keys.

Comment: @zerkms command_keys is just the keys of commands, e.g. Object.keys(commands); I added this to the questions. Right, the keys of commands  are strings and some_array is an array of strings.

Comment: @PraveenKumar The keys of commands  are strings and some_array is an array of strings. Adding this to the question.

Comment: The `.indexOf()` function returns the **index** of the searched-for key in the array, not the key itself. *edit* but if `some_array` is an array then you're doing something completely incorrect anyway; it's hard to tell what it is you expect that to do.

Comment: @Pointy My fault, it's not an array but a string. In the original problem I loop through an array, but that's of no interest here. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @JosiahKeller You're right. I just replaced some_array with some_string.

Comment: @Randomtheories so, check my second comment once again then, it still explains your mistake. It makes sense if you explain what you want to achieve, even though your current code is helpful to understand the problem it does not shed any light on the original aim.

Comment: @zerkms you're right, it works now - stupid mistake. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need `command_keys` at all.  `commands` alone will suffice for what you describe here.

```
var commands = {
    'key1': someFunction,
    'key2': otherFunction
};

var command = commands[some_string];
if (typeof command === 'function') {
    command(some_param);
}
```

Comment: What if `command_keys` is some sort of filter of applicable commands in a given context? Like, we have an `edit` command but we cannot perform it when something is in a `read-only` mode.

Comment: Well then, you could keep it around and add another condition to the if `typeof command === 'function' && command_keys.indexOf(some_string) !== -1`.  `command_keys` is still not useful for retrieving the actual command from `commands` based on `some_string`, though.

Comment: That's right. My point was that you cannot put the "I don't think you need command_keys at all" statement unless some more details provided. PS: oh, I just noticed `var command_keys = Object.keys(commands);`, so seems right it's indeed redundant.

Comment: @NoahFreitas. Thanks for pointing this out. I solved the problem thanks to zerkms as I used the index instead of the key.